# what are the options to store small amount of data that needs to be queried frequently in an asp.net core app

Tags: sql, database, asp.net-core, nosql

I'm currently working on a project that needs to store data of about 5 to 10 entities and at most 5000 records for each of them.

I was thinking about using mysql or postgres or even mongodb but all of them seems to be a lot for this little data

What I'm looking for is a database that can query this little amount of data but frequently

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SQLite` DB

SQLite is a lightweight C library that provided a relational database storage engine. Everything in this database lives in a single file that you can put anywhere in your filesystem. And that’s all you need to use it!

**Useful features**

- Full support for transactions, with COMMIT, ROLLBACK, and BEGIN.
- Support for 32,000 columns per table JSON support 64-way JOIN support
  Subqueries
- Full-text search
- Maximum database size of 140
  terabytes! Maximum row size of 1 gigabyte! 35% faster than file I/O